# how to run script on database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, web

I am currently makin a web application in asp.net. where I want to delete all records from database which is older than 1 month. how can I delete them on server side by running any type of script. or any other type of suggestion which I useful in my scenario. thanks and  sorry I am new to web development and forgive me if I a asking blunder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sql query would be something like this;

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE DateField < DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())
```

You'd have to do it at a table level, you can't do it for a whole database as each table is likely to have different fields in a different order.

Comment: where should I place this query, like I want that database itself delete this after one month, is it possible?

Comment: You can put a job that runs every night into sql server agent